# Merge double integers with different decimal places

Tags: r

I want to merge two datasets based on their double integers, however one of the falls short 2 decimal places but I would like to merge them regardless if all units from the short match its relative length to the longer. The final integer can be of the longer or shorter one.

Example with expectation (xy):

```
x = c(0.456, 0.797, 0.978, 0.897, 0.567)
x1 = c(0.45698, 0.79786, 0.97895, 0.75869, 0.56049)

x           x1
0.456  0.45698
0.797  0.79786
0.978  0.97895

# or if they match then replace with longer integers
```

I have tried merge but it duplicates:

```
> xx1<-merge(x, x1)
> unique(xx1)
      x      x1
1 0.456 0.45698
2 0.797 0.45698
3 0.978 0.45698
4 0.456 0.79786
5 0.797 0.79786
6 0.978 0.79786
7 0.456 0.97895
8 0.797 0.97895
9 0.978 0.97895
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmatch`:

```
i <- pmatch(x, x1)
j <- !is.na(i)
cbind(x=x[j], x1=x1[i[j]])
#         x      x1
#[1,] 0.456 0.45698
#[2,] 0.797 0.79786
#[3,] 0.978 0.97895
```

Comment: Do you know of faster functions than`match`that does the same thing? it is very slow with larger datasets

Comment: For `match` I know `fastmatch::fmatch` but for `pmatch` I don't know a faster function.